# Viewing 100-200ns pulse on oscillocope

Tags: oscilloscope, pulse, time, test-equipment

I've recently bought a [Gould OS300 dual trace 20MHz oscilloscope.](http://www.radiomanual.info/schemi/ACC_instrument/Gould_OS300_user.pdf)

I'm trying to view a 100ns to 200ns pulse, but I'm not sure I'm using the correct settings.

The pulse voltage goes from 3.80V to 0V so I set the volts/cm to 2 then 5 but couldn't see anything. I then set the time base to 10 microseconds per cm but again I saw nothing. I'm not sure if I'm just using this the completely wrong way.

[image: 2]

Comment: Use the Cal 1V signal to calibrate 10:1 probe for a square edge and adjust trigger threshold.  Then connect to signal and see if adjusting trigger will work.

Comment: Hi, I adjusted for a square edge and when I connect back to the signal, It's a very faint straight vertical line that spikes but it's hardly noticeable and is very fast.

Comment: Is your probe a 1:1 type or 10:1 attenuator type? If it is a 10:1 attenuator type (as Tony has assumed), then you must mentally change the **VOLTS/CM** scale... So that a 3.8V pulse fills the screen, you'd set **VOLTS/CM** to 50mV. or perhaps .1V. You MUST also turn the **Var Sens** knob fully clockwise toward the Cal position.

Comment: @glen_geek it's a 10:1 attenuator type.  What do you mean by "mentally" changing the volts/cm scale?

Comment: You should use the fastest time sweep 0.1us.div and look again. if the rep rate is low , it will be faint and select Off for Bright line rather than Ch 2

Comment: The **VOLTS/CM** scale assumes your probe is straight 1:1. When you use an attenuator probe, you must mentally scale by ten. For example, 0.1V knob position is actually 1V when a 10:1 probe is used.

Comment: I only get a proper square edge on calibration when it's set to 2V/cm and 20us/cm. @TonyStewartEE75 even at the fastest time sweep I can't see very much

Comment: Use a hood to see it better if the rep rate or duty cycle is extremely low.

Comment: @38150_piled:  Is that a single pulse or does it repeat?  If it's a single pulse, you'll need to get the trigger set to fire only when your pulse occurs, then use a camera to caputure the pulse when it flits by.

Comment: When you say **pulse**!  Is that singular or repetitive?  My money is on singular.  If it was repetitive, you'd see something.  Scopes are good for seeing repetitive signals.

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to assume that when you say "pulse", you mean a pulse train at some frequency greater than about 10 Hz.

First and most important - take a look at your scope probe. Is it a 1x or a 10x probe (if it's 10x it will say so). If it's a 1x probe, as I suspect it is from your picture, you are going to have a lot of trouble seeing a 100 nsec pulse. If you have the switchable 1x/10x probe which came with the scope, switch it to 10x.

If your expected pulse is a negative-going pulse, set the trigger to "-" using the +/- button to the left of the "Mag" button. Otherwise, set the trigger to "+".

With no input, use your vertical position knob to set your baseline about 2 divisions higher than you are now if you expect a negative-going pulse. Otherwise, set it about 2 divisions lower than it is now. Then set the sensitivity to 0.1 v/cm. This will give you about 4 divisions of vertical deflection, centered around the center of your screen.

Set your timebase to its limit, in this case 0.5 uSec/div. Note that at this speed, a 100 nsec pulse will only take up 1/5 of a horizontal division.

Set the switch next to your probe to AC, not DC.

Now turn the "Trig Level" knob to a bit left of its center position if you are expecting a negative pulse, or to the right for a positive pulse.

At this point, assuming you have a pulse frequency of more than about 10 Hz, you should see your pulse at the left hand side of a trace. If you have a trace but don't see the pulse, try moving the trace to the right using the <> knob - the start of the trace may be off the screen to the left. If not, try rotating your trigger level knob a bit in either direction. Once you have a pulse at the left-hand edge of the trace, you can expand it by pushing the "Mag" button to 10x.

If your pulse is generated from a very slow source, like pushing a button, be aware that this scope is really not for you. You need a scope which will respond to single trigger events.

Looking at 100 nsec pulses with this scope is doable, but it's right at the edge of the scope's capabilities.

Comment: Hi, I've tried all of the above and still don't get any pulse.

Comment: @38150_piled - 1, what is your pulse rate? - 2,what type of probe are you using? 3, have you been able to display the CAL waveform?

Comment: The probes I'm using are here :https://www.amazon.co.uk/gp/product/B08JHYSRKH/ref=ppx_yo_dt_b_asin_title_o00_s00?ie=UTF8&psc=1. My pulse is being repeated by an arduino and has a 100ns pulse width. I displayed the cal waveform but not in the setting required for a small pulse

Comment: @38150_piled - And one more time - what is your pulse rate?

Comment: @38150_piled - And just as an experiment, try changing the pulse width to 1 usec, and see if you can detect that.

Comment: I'm getting a signal now but it's meant to follow the pattern of a square wave and I'm getting  a sort of sine wave/zig-zag shape

Comment: @38150_piled - So the Arduino is not putting out a simple pulse. This probably says that at 100 nsec you're not getting a pulse at all - which would explain why you don't see it. As to why, I have no idea. Just to check - are you connecting the ground clip on the scope probe as close to the Arduino as you can? For fast edges, you need to use short ground leads connected as close to the signal source as you can.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you're using a 10x probe, yes? Those are by far the most common type.

When using a 10x probe, all voltages measured are attenuated by a factor of 10, so your 3.8 volt signal will appear to the scope as 0.38 volts. Modern digital scopes will automatically compensate for this for you and show it as 3.8 volts, but an analog scope like you're using won't; you'll need to set the vertical scale to something more like 100 mV per division in order to see it.

Answer (score 0):

Your O'scope must be triggered to start a sweep BEFORE the signal arrives on-screen.

In other words, the pulse triggers the scope to start its sweep;
Then with the signal for display showing up later.  IT'S  A FAST-MOVING BUGGER, ain't  it ??